# I have a problem with switch in Android Studio

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I made the code I made the app design, but when I added the switch on the app design it kept on showing me the "Replace usage of 'Switch' widget." I'm not sure with problem it is my first time with Android Studio

```xml
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/sw_compact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="@string/activecustomer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber" />
```

this my problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just use SwitchCompat? It's the same thing as Switch, only allowing for backward compatibility (see [docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SwitchCompat)).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to be worried. It is just a warning because you are using AppCompatActivity. It supports material design and animations. We can say that is classy than classical 'Switch'. It is safe to migrate to 'SwitchCompat' as that contains more features.